# How Can I Show Custom 500 Internal Server Error Pages with Lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd

I can handle 404 error with a static page on lighttpd but can't handle 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `server.errorfile-prefix` configuration option: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Server.errorfile-prefixDetails

Comment: This can not work. Lighttpd can not handle 500 erros generated on **php** pages.